# Orderby C# string record

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following orderby for a record read from db and then building a string.
The following code works fine but I know this can be improved any suggestion is highly appreciated.

```
  result.Sites.ForEach(x =>
                {
                    result.SiteDetails +=
                        string.Concat(ICMSRepository.Instance.GetSiteInformationById(x.SiteInformationId).SiteCode,
                            ",");
                });
                //Sort(Orderby) sites by string value NOT by numerical order
                result.SiteDetails = result.SiteDetails.Trim(',');
                List<string> siteCodes = result.SiteDetails.Split(',').ToList();
                var siteCodesOrder = siteCodes.OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();
                string siteCodesSorted = string.Join(", ", siteCodesOrder);
                result.SiteDetails = siteCodesSorted;
```

Answer (score 5):

That's a little convoluted, yeah.

All we need to do is select out the `SiteCode` as string, sort with `OrderBy`, then join the results.  Since `String::Join` has a variant that works with `IEnumerable<string>` we don't need to convert to array in the middle.

What we end up with is a single statement for assigning to your `SiteDetails` member:

```
result.SiteDetails = string.Join(", ", 
    result.Sites
    .Select(x => $"{ICMSRepository.Instance.GetSiteInformationById(x.SiteInformationId).SiteCode}")
    .OrderBy(x => x)
);
```

(Or you could use `.ToString()` instead of `$"{...}"`)

---

This is the general process for most transforms in LINQ.  Figure out what your inputs are, what you need to do with them, and how the outputs should look.

If you're using LINQ it's uncommon that you will have to build and manipulate intermediary lists unless you're doing something quite complex.  For simple tasks like sorting a sequence of values there is almost never a reason to put them into transitional collections, since the framework handles all of that for you.

And the best part is it enumerates the collection one time to get the full set of data.  No more loops to pull the data out, then process, then rebuild.

Answer (score -1):

One thing that will improve performance is to get rid of the `.ToList()` and the `.ToString`. Neither is necessary and just take up extra processing time and memory.

Answer (score -1):

Go with Corey's answer, which this is a variant of, but I thought I'd offer a slightly clearer way to express the query:

```
result.SiteDetails =
    String.Join(", ",
        from x in result.Sites
        let sc = ICMSRepository.Instance.GetSiteInformationById(x.SiteInformationId).SiteCode
        orderby sc
        select sc);
```